# without app in project django models not showing in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've not created any apps in my django project, when I try to register the models if doesn't show up in admin, I've made and applied migrations.
If I do this while creating app it works fine, but without app I face issues.

Here's the code to `models.py`;

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and `admin.py`;

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Customer
admin.site.register(Customer)
```

I've gone through other questions, what I found is all about models in apps, or maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

django looks for apps in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

Then in every app django looks for modules, templates etc. and also for registrations to admin page in a admin.py file. That is why the app structure is needed.

Comment: so it is not possible to register without an app, right??

Comment: well you can always try to do things manually but there will more side effects then just the admin registration if you do not create an app. Django is based on apps structure. e.g. during migration the app name is added to the model name in the db table ....